# "No matching records found" NOT displayed in "bootstrap-table"

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using the "bootstrap-table"(https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) plugin for my website and currently using it's server side pagination properties.

The table is being populated correctly and the search feature also works.
BUT when something not present is searched for, it displays all the records **instead of displaying "No matching records found".**

This is the html code I am using...

```
<table data-toggle="table"
       data-url="1.php"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-side-pagination="server"
       data-page-list="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]"
       data-search="true"
       data-height="300">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="memberID" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Member ID</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-align="center" data-sortable="true"> Name</th>
        <th data-field="dob" data-sortable="true">Date of Birth</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>


</table>
```

and this is the php script I am using to create the JSON response...

```
<?php

require_once('db-connect.php');

if(isset($_GET["limit"])) {
    $limit = $_GET["limit"];
} else {
    $limit = 10;
}

if(isset($_GET["offset"])) {
    $offset = $_GET["offset"];
} else {
    $offset = 0;
}

if(isset($_GET["sort"])) {
    $sort = $_GET["sort"];
} else {
    $sort = "";
}

if(isset($_GET["order"])) {
    $order = $_GET["order"];
} else {
    $order = "asc";
}

 if(isset($_GET["search"])) {
    $search = $_GET["search"];
 } else {
    $search = "";
 }


if($search == "") {
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select memberID, name, dob from memberdetails" );
} else {

    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"select memberID, name, dob from memberdetails WHERE memberID LIKE '%$search%'"  );
}


$row = array();

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $result_2d_arr[] = array (  'memberID' => $row['memberID'],
                                            'name' => $row['name'],
                                            'dob' => $row['dob']);
            }




//get the result size
$count = sizeof($result_2d_arr);

//order the array
if($order != "asc") {
    $result_2d_arr = array_reverse($result_2d_arr);
}

//get the subview of the array
$result_2d_arr = array_slice($result_2d_arr, $offset, $limit);



echo "{";
echo '"total": ' . $count . ',';
echo '"rows": ';
echo json_encode($result_2d_arr);
echo "}";

}

?>
```

The JSON response is as follows...

```
{"total": 23,"rows": [{"memberID":"1","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"2","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"3","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"4","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"5","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"6","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"7","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"8","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"9","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"},{"memberID":"10","name":"asd","dob":"2015-06-03"}]}
```

Comment: have you checked the num_rows, when the searched entry is not present in your table? If it returns 0 then add the else condition for `if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) { .. } else { echo "No results found";}` and pass the values to your html file

Comment: I assume memberID will always be an integer, I would not use LIKE '%$var%' when searching for an integer, as ID 1 would match 11 or 101 I guess this is the issue, as your field memberID is probably assigned as Integer it may be useful to use WHERE CAST(memberID AS TEXT) LIKE '%$search%' if you are intent on using the LIKE operator. I would simply switch to a = operator and search specifically for the ID

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did try both the methods mentioned above but the outcome remained same. I have been referencing these documents to  write most of my code. [link](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/examples.html#server-side-pagination-table) [link](http://jsfiddle.net/4r6g4cfu/3/light/)  Hope this makes the question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally...got it working. I put this code in the else part.

```
else {
$count=0;
echo "{";
echo '"total": ' . $count . ',';
echo '"rows": ';
echo json_encode(array());
echo "}";
}
```